# How to restrinc user votes

Tags: php, symfony

I implemented a vote system for my users on a forumbundle. It works fine but I would like to restrinct and just let vote 1 time for user. So I create a Boolean voted on my bdd.
But I don't know how should I can avoid that user's can vote again but at the same time I'd like to let them undo the vote.

So I made this  function :

```
 public function ScoreAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $idTopic = $request->request->get('id_topic');       

    $idPoster = $request->request->get('id_poster');

    $positive= $request->request->get('positive');
    $negative= $request->request->get('negatiu');

    $user=  $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneById($idPoster); 

    $topic = $em->getRepository(Topic::class)->findOneById($idTopic); 


    $score= $user->getReputation();
    $voted = $user->getVoted();
    if ($positive!= null) {
        $score= $score+ 1;
        $voted = 1;
    }
    if($negative!= null){
         $score= $score- 1;
         $voted = 1;
    }

    $user->setReputation($score);
    $user->setVoted($voted);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();


    $redirect = $this->generateUrl('discutea_forum_post', array('slug' => $topic->getSlug())); 

    return $this->redirect($redirect);
}
```

***Update with change boolean for int nullable on my Database and made this code:***

```
     $score = $user->getReputation();
    $voted = $user->getVoted();

    if ($voted == null) {                  
        if ($positive != null) {
            $score = $score + 1;
            $voted = 1;
        }
        if($negative != null){
             $score = $score - 1;
             $voted = 0;
        }
    }else if($voted == 1){
        if ($negative != null) {
            $score = $score - 1;
            $voted = 0;
        }
    }else if($voted == 0){
        if ($positive != null) {
            $score = $score + 1;
            $voted = 1;
        }
    }


    $user->setReputation($score);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: So you made this function... and? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Daniel I can't deny that user's can undo his vote.

Comment: I don't know with symfony, but the logic should be: "Exists a row associated with the user in the votes table ? If yes, the user already voted, user cant vote again and user can undo (remove row) vote. If does not exists, can vote."

Comment: I tried to implement and else option to undo the vote but didn't work.

Comment: WHAT have you tried ?  post the code ?  what was the expected result vs the actual result ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$voted = $user->getVoted();

if ($voted) {
    //just redirect somewhere else, without making an actual vote
} else {
    //do your vote stuff
    //persist and flush etc
    //redirect somewhere else
}
```

something along those lines ?

are you trying to achieve the following  ?:

```
$voted = $user->getVoted();

if ($voted) {
    if ($positive!= null) {
        $user->setReputation($user->setReputation()+2);
    }
    if ($negative!= null){
         $user->setReputation($user->setReputation()-2);
    }
} else {
    if ($positive!= null) {
        $user->setReputation($user->setReputation()+1);
    }
    if ($negative!= null){
         $user->setReputation($user->setReputation()-1);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

try this

```
if ($voted === null) {                  
    if ($positive != null) {
        $score = $score + 1;
    }
    if($negative != null){
         $score = $score - 1;
    }
}else if($voted === 1){
    if ($negative != null) {
        $score = $score - 1;
    }
}else if($voted === 0){
    if ($positive != null) {
        $score = $score + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to let user to change his vote. @SamJanssens

Comment: You want their 'score' to be changed again ?   would this not mean they are voting again ?   what do you mean by 'change their vote' ?

Comment: Imagine that you are an user and want to vote positive to other user but you missclick and vote negative. You'd like to change your vote. @SamJanssens

Comment: yes but what should happen,   if i am a user, i already voted +,   and now i vote -,   should my 'score' property be updated ?

Comment: if i previously voted + (and you did score+1),   and i shange it to -,   should it to score-2, instead of score-1 ?   is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that If I vote +1 and I missclick and want to vote -1. When I vote -1 will rest 1.  I mean if I want to change my vote I could but just +1 or -1 I'dont want to increment -1 -1 -1 or +1 +1 +1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146244/discussion-between-sam-janssens-and-pillow).

Comment: Updated @SamJanssens